# Neo4j 3.0.1 - Neomodel 2.0.7 - Parameter provided for node creation is not a Map

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo, neomodel

I am trying out the Neomodel Source Code to make it work with Neo4j 3.0.1. I am facing this eeror saying that the Parameters provided for node creation is not a Map.

{u'errors': [{u'message': u'Parameter provided for node creation is not a Map', u'code': u'Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError'}], u'results': []}

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/adaggula/Documents/workspace/Collective[i]-pve/test_revised.py", line 32, in <module>
        jim = Person(name='jim5').save()
      File "/Users/adaggula/workspace/python/pve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neomodel/signals.py", line 25, in hooked
        val = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/adaggula/workspace/python/pve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neomodel/core.py", line 160, in save
        self._id = self.create(self.__properties__)[0]._id
      File "/Users/adaggula/workspace/python/pve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neomodel/core.py", line 290, in create
        results = db.cypher_query(query, params)
      File "/Users/adaggula/workspace/python/pve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neomodel/util.py", line 219, in cypher_query
        results = self._execute_query(query, params)
      File "/Users/adaggula/workspace/python/pve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neomodel/util.py", line 212, in _execute_query
        results = self.session.cypher.execute(query, params)
      File "/Users/adaggula/workspace/python/pve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/cypher/core.py", line 113, in execute
        results = tx.commit()
      File "/Users/adaggula/workspace/python/pve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/cypher/core.py", line 325, in commit
        return self.post(self.__commit or self.__begin_commit)
      File "/Users/adaggula/workspace/python/pve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/cypher/core.py", line 280, in post
        raise self.error_class.hydrate(error)
      File "/Users/adaggula/workspace/python/pve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/cypher/error/core.py", line 54, in hydrate
        error_cls = getattr(error_module, title)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TypeError'
```

What are the changes I should make to make it work?

Comment: did you solve this? or which another library did you used to integrate neo4j 3.x with neomodel 2.0.x? Am stuck with same compatibility issues this was my 2nd trial, I have even tried with neo4django which also is not compatible

Comment: There is no upgrades for Neomodel to compatible with the Neo4j 3.x. Neomodel Community replied that they are working on the upgrade. Hope we find it soon.

Comment: Thanks. I reverted back to neo4j-community-2.2.9 version and using neomodel 2.0.2